# Finding data change in a column of numbers with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a large csv table with data like:

```
Loop_3_OP   Loop_3_PV   Line1_Cleaning  Line2_Cleaning  time            date
59.17       29.63       0               0               18:00:33.239000 2015-11-01
59.17       29.63       0               0               18:00:34.231000 2015-11-01
```

Throughout the table, Line1_Cleaning and Line2_Cleaning change between 0 and 1 like:

```
59.17       29.63       0              0                 18:06:22.343000    2015-11-01
59.17       29.63       1              0                 18:06:34.565000    2015-11-01
59.17       29.63       1              0                 18:06:34.565000    2015-11-01
59.17       29.63       1              0                 18:06:35.918000    2015-11-01
59.17       29.63       1              0                 18:06:35.918000    2015-11-01
59.17       29.63       0              0                 18:06:35.929000    2015-11-01
```

I'd like to be able to pick up just the rows when the transition occurs, like:

```
59.17       29.63       1              0                 18:06:34.565000    2015-11-01
```

I can do it in traditional python iterating over rows:

```
read = csv.reader(ifile)
for row in read :
   val= row[2]
   if val>lastval:
        print val, row[4],"L1 Start Clean"
   lastval=val
```

I was wondering if anyone could offer if it can be done in Pandas.  I'm working though Anaconda and iPython, and would like 
to see if it is possible.

Regards

Comment: Sorry are you after `read[read['Line1_Cleaning'] != read['Line1_Cleaning'].shift()]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for current `Line1_Cleaning` is greater than `previous line Line1_Cleaning` value then extract extract the line. Which is only `Line1_Cleaning` changes from `0 to 1`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(ifile)
final_df = df[df['Line1_Cleaning'] > df['Line1_Cleaning'].shift(1)]
print final_df
```

Comment: This is incredible- thank you.  I was unaware of the shift function.  I will have to research it.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can use [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html#pandas.Series.diff):

```
In [16]:
df[df['Line1_Cleaning'].diff() > 0]

Out[16]:
   Loop_3_OP  Loop_3_PV  Line1_Cleaning  Line2_Cleaning             time  \
3      59.17      29.63               1               0  18:06:34.565000   

        date  
3 2015-11-01
```

So this calls `diff` to subtract the rows against the previous rows and filters them where this diff is `>0`

The output from `diff`:

```
In [17]:
df['Line1_Cleaning'].diff()

Out[17]:
0   NaN
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     0
5     0
6     0
7    -1
Name: Line1_Cleaning, dtype: float64
```

Comment: :) well i didn't actually understand your solution so posted mine

Answer (score 0):

[`numpy.diff`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) may be useful here: calculate the diff per column, and where the diff != 0 you'll find the row indices. You can combine the diffs for the two columns using a boolean or, and don't forget to offset your indices by 1.

Something like:

```
diff1 = np.diff(table['Line1_Cleaning'])
diff2 = np.diff(...

diff = (diff1 != 0) | (diff2 != 0)
indices = np.arange(len(diff))[diff] + 1
changing_rows = table.ix[indices]
```

(Completely untested.)

---

(Perhaps there's a `diff` function/method in Pandas as well, but I'm more familiar with numpy.)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to select the rows if `Line1_Cleaning` value is `1`. If so, you can just do this:

```
df = df[df.Line1_Cleaning == 1]
```

Comment: No, WoodChopper had it correct - I am looking for the transition of Line1_Cleaning going from 0 to 1